# C# and utf8_decode

Tags: c#, php, utf-8, utf8-decode

Is there a C# [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) equivalent?

Comment: As a side note, .NET string/char are already UTF-16.

Comment: But utf8_decode() _takes_ an utf8 encoded string and returns an iso-8859-1 string.

Comment: @VolkerK: That would be why it was a side note.  The user doesn't specify where the text to encode is coming from, so I mentioned what format .NET strings are by default.

Comment: Ah I see, good point. If you (already) have a System.String it's utf-16 encoded <-> System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, **not** utf-8 <-> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class.

For example:

```
byte[] bytes = something;
string str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can use the [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to convert the encoding.

```
string source = "Déjà vu";
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;
// iso-8859-1 <- codepage 28591
Encoding latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591); 
Byte[] result = Encoding.Convert(unicode, latin1, unicode.GetBytes(s));
// result contains the byte sequence for the latin1 encoded string
```

edit: or simply

```
string source = "Déjà vu";
Byte[] latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(source);
```

string (System.String) is always unicode encoded, i.e. if you convert the byte sequence back to string ([Encoding.GetString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring.aspx)) your data will again be stored as utf-16 codepoints again.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is a string here is a method that would probably work (assuming your from wester europe :)

```
public string Utf8Decode(string inputDate)
{
    return Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputDate));
}
```

Of course, if the current encoding of the inputData is not latin1, change the "iso-8859-1" to the correct encoding.

Comment: This will return a System.String as if `inputDate` was (falsely) utf8 encoded but really contains an iso-8859-1 byte sequence. E.g. inputDate="Déjà vu". UTF8.GetBytes() returns the sequence {68, 195, 169, 106, 195, 160, 32, 118, 117 }. ("iso-8859-1").GetString() will interpret each single byte (since it's a single-byte encoding) as a character. The resulting string is `DÃ©jÃ  vu`

Comment: Hello, the user was refering to a php function.

It is probably because he has some wrongly encoded "string", I mean something like 'DÃ©jÃ  vu' and want it to become 'Déjà vu'. 

This happens when you communicate with a mysql server with a utf8 encoding and you forget to specify the utf8 charset in the connection string.

But I agree with you, utf8decode on a .NET string is not a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make this implementation on Xamarin C#.

The code below worked for me:

```cs
        public static string Utf8Encode(string inputDate)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputDate);
            return Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(bytes,0, bytes.Length);
        }

        public static string Utf8Decode(string inputDate)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(inputDate);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
```